# page appears differently without www subdomain in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

I am not sure what it is but page renders very differently without www subdomain i think it has something to do with my hidden div jQuery layout. Any ideas?

works fine in ie / firefox / android webkit browser. Just don't work in Chrome??

try the without www. first then add www. and you'll see (if you do it in reverse it will render correctly just close tab and open new one).

http://josefscountryinn.com/

Thank You!

*edit* no longer a www issue its how chrome renders the page sometimes it renders correctly if you refresh

heres a screenshot of chrome left firefox right (cant post screenshot cause im new)

http://www.josefscountryinn.com/sc1.jpg

Comment: I tried this with Chrome 20 and couldn't see any difference.  What exactly should I be looking for?

Comment: I also tried it with Chrome and compared the html-code. It was exactly the same.

Comment: I think I found the problem - The paragraph starting with "Welcome to Josef's Country Inn, wh..." is positioned correctly when the page is opened for the first time but on refreshing it falls down. This has nothing to do with using www. or not. It would be better if you could post a snapshot of the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: @cyclotrojan yeah that is the problem that i am facing, i checked now and it does it on both www and non www. any idea whats causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks the same to me. You can always force it to either have www or not have it. If you want it to force no www then add the following code to .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.josefscountryinn.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://josefscountryinn.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont think it has something to do with www anymore @cyclotrojan see's the issue i am talking about i dont  what is causeing that???

Comment: Change the height of the class "fadein" to 100px instead of 400px.

Comment: thanks but here is the prob that im having (left chrome) http://www.josefscountryinn.com/sc1.jpg